# How to correctly create method that returns a Type in C# (Java to C# translation)

Tags: c#, java, types

I am currently working on porting some code from Java to C#.

I have encountered a problem with a code that in Java is not too difficult:

```
public static Object getJavaDataType(DataType dataType) {
        switch (dataType) {
        case Boolean:
            return Boolean.class;
        case Date:
            return java.util.Date.class;
        case Integer:
            return Integer.class;
        case String:
            return String.class;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I am having difficulties in translating this into C#. So far my best efforts look similar to this:

```
public static Type getJavaDataType(DataType dataType) {
            if(dataType == BooleanType){
                return Type.GetType("Boolean");
            } else if ...
```

So I have managed to deal with the fact that Enum is transformed into public sealed class:

```
public sealed class DataType
    {
        public static readonly DataType BooleanType = new DataType(); ...
```

But the type code does not look correct to me (does it really have to be specified by String?). Does someone know more elegant implementation of this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `typeof`, i.e.

- `typeof(bool)`
- `typeof(int)`
- `typeof(string)`
- `typeof(DateTime)`

Oh, and enums are supported in C# just as well:

```
public enum DataType
{
    Boolean,
    String,
    Integer
}
```

Usage would be:

```
case DataType.String:
    return typeof(string);
```

---

Update:

Instead of using a class with `static readonly` fields, because you need to add a method to the enum, you can use extension methods instead.

It would look like this:

```
public enum DataType
{
    Boolean,
    String,
    Integer
}

public static class DataTypeExtensions
{
    public static Type GetCsharpDataType(this DataType dataType)
    {
        switch(dataType)
        {
            case DataType.Boolen:
                return typeof(bool);
            case DataType.String:
                return typeof(string);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dataType");
        }
    }
}
```

Usage would be like this:

```
var dataType = DataType.Boolean;
var type = dataType.GetCsharpDataType();
```

Comment: I know enums are supported, but in my case- I had this method inside an enum. Anyway- thanks, answers my question perfectly.

Comment: @jedrus07: Yes, that's right: Enums don't support methods in C#. The solution you chose (with the static readonly fields in a class) is one way to do this in C#, however, an alternative approach with an extension method would also be possible and actually preferred. Please see update for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the bets example of enum in C#:

```
public enum DataType
{
    Boolean,
    Date,
    Integer,
    String
}
```

And here your method:

```
public static Type getJavaDataType(DataType dataType)
{
    switch (dataType)
    {
        case DataType.Boolean:
            return typeof(bool);
        case DataType.Date:
            return typeof(DateTime);
        case DataType.Integer:
            return typeof(int);
        case DataType.String:
            return typeof(string);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible by using Switch statement unless converted to Type Name.

```
        switch (dataType.GetType().Name)
        {
            case "TextBox":
                break;

        }
        return null;
```